# Detect UIkeyboard type currently being shown?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I need to know type of uikeyboard which is currently being shown.

Is there any way to find this? i searched for this but still i dont get any solution.

Please let me know

Comment: you can check in the interface builder for any text field or textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with an UITextfield, you can get this information with 'keyboardType' property :

textField.keyboardType

Apple Doc :

```
typedef enum {
UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
#if __IPHONE_4_1 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,             // A number pad with a decimal point.
#endif
#if __IPHONE_5_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
UIKeyboardTypeTwitter,                // A type optimized for twitter text entry (easy access to @ #)
#endif

UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, // Deprecated

} UIKeyboardType;
```

Comment: annoyingly this seems to only reflect what you initially set the keyboard type to be. eg. if the user switches to 'numbers and punctuation' keyboardType won't be updated

Comment: This solution is incorrect, coz UITextField doesn't know, which keyboard currently is shown, it just show this type on becomeFirstResponder. When user change it's type, keyboardType doesn't reflect the information, it still has defaultType.